# Como puedo mapear 2 rutas en el web.xml en spring

Tags: java, spring

Quisiera hacer un segundo mapping en el servlet de spring para que a parte de mapear todas las rutas que empiecen con "/app", tambien mapee todas las rutas que empiecen con "/ws".

Con el codigo aqui abajo si uso http://localhost:8080/springMVC/app/index.htm, obtengo la misma pagina que si usase http://localhost:8080/springMVC/ws/index.htm

Pero lo que quiero es usar rutas que empiecen en "/app" solo para paginas normales con @ Controller y "/ws" solo para hacer llamadas a web services usando @ RestController. Es decir:
    http://localhost:8080/springMVC/app/index.htm
    http://localhost:8080/springMVC/ws/users/listarREST

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="Controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="RestController"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ServiceImpl"/>


<bean id="viewResolver"  
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

PrincipalContoller.java

```
import Entidades.Usuario;
import ServiceImpl.UsuarioServiceImpl;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class PrincipalController {
@Autowired
UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioService;


@RequestMapping(value="/index.htm", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listar(){
    List datos=usuarioService.listar();
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("index");
    mv.addObject("usuarios",datos);
    mv.addObject("user",new Usuario());
    System.out.println("OBJ: "+datos);
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/agregar.htm", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView agregar(Usuario u){
    usuarioService.agregar(u);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/editar.htm", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editar(HttpServletRequest request){
    int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    String contrasena=request.getParameter("contrasena");
    usuarioService.cambiarContrasena(contrasena, id);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
}
}
```

PrincipalRestController

```
@RestController
public class PrincipalRestController {

@Resource(name="usuarioServiceImpl")
UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioService;

@RequestMapping(value="/users/listarREST", method= RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody String listar(){
    List datos=usuarioService.listar();
    return usuarioService.listar().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener ambos procesos sin problemas. Si tienes activado el spring security  debes habilitar dos canales.

clase principal

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
```

configuracion 1

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class RestfulSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

configuracion 2

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class WebLoginSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Sino tienes problemas con esto. Entonces en el servicio restful debes colocar el nombre base de la ruta

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ws") //ruta base: localhost:8080/ws
public class MicroServiciosController {

@GetMapping("/inicio") // endpoint: localhost:8080/ws/inicio
public ResponseEntity<String> bienvenida() { System.out.println("Ejecutando rest inicio");
```

y en cuanto a la pagina web que es el otro servicio, se puede hacer de varias formas....esta es una manera.(pom.xml) "finalName"

```
<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

La otra es cambiar el "context" con server.xml y si el servidor es embebido seria en applications.properties. (investigar todo)